# GitLab - Error 404 on artifact upload for large artifacts

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, http-status-code-404, limit

I am self-hosting a private Gitlab 15.0.2 on Gentoo using this overlay: https://gitlab.awesome-it.de/overlays/gitlab

It's basically an installation from source (no Omnibus). Now I have also configured a gitlab runner (docker based) and a CI pipeline in one of my projects (a homepage being generated through hugo). The pipeline works fine up the the point where it is supposed to upload the artifact which is currently about 11GB in size.

Initially this gave me an "413 Request Entity Too Large" error, so I raised the artifact size limits in Gitlab and increased the client_max_body_size in Nginx. Now I am seeing this error instead:

```
Uploading artifacts for successful job
Using docker image sha256:c20c992e5d83348903a6f8d18b4005ed1db893c4f97a61e1cd7a8a06c2989c40 for registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/gitlab-runner-helper:x86_64-latest with digest registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/gitlab-runner-helper@sha256:edc1bf6ab9e1c7048d054b270f79919eabcbb9cf052b3e5d6f29c886c842bfed ...
Uploading artifacts...
public: found 907 matching files and directories   
WARNING: Uploading artifacts as "archive" to coordinator... 404 Not Found  id=112 responseStatus=404 Not Found status=404 token=X8QjapaV
WARNING: Retrying...                                context=artifacts-uploader error=invalid argument
WARNING: Uploading artifacts as "archive" to coordinator... 404 Not Found  id=112 responseStatus=404 Not Found status=404 token=X8QjapaV
WARNING: Retrying...                                context=artifacts-uploader error=invalid argument
WARNING: Uploading artifacts as "archive" to coordinator... 404 Not Found  id=112 responseStatus=404 Not Found status=404 token=X8QjapaV
FATAL: invalid argument                            
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

It tries 3 times before eventually giving up. Each attempt takes a few minutes.

I am not seeing any messages related to this in Gitlab's production.log which leaves me a bit stumped. The 404 error code does not seem to make much sense in this context. I have tested the build pipeline by branching and removing lots of content to create a much smaller artifact. The upload works in that branch on first try, so the upload URL must be fine.

Are there any other configuration settings that I need to be aware of? Perhaps some timeout for the upload?

EDIT:
Here's my current .gitlab-ci.yaml to give you better idea of what I am doing. It's rather ugly with those NodeJS dependencies being installed every time the pipeline is run, but that's currently not the issue.

```
image: cibuilds/hugo

variables:
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive

build:
  stage: build
  script:
  - curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x -o /tmp/nodesource_setup.sh
  - sudo bash /tmp/nodesource_setup.sh
  - sudo apt update
  - sudo apt install nodejs
  - npm install autoprefixer postcss-cli
  - hugo
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
```

I am planning to add another step to the pipeline for the deployment using rsync over ssh.

Comment: Did you update the max size size of pages in the admin settings? under admin -> settings -> preferences -> pages

Comment: I am not actually using Gitlab Pages and I added my pipeline to show this. Though I did also just give it a try anyway (increased the limit to 1 TB), just in case I misunderstand how Gitlab Pages work. Same result with the 404 error.

Comment: I think you have everything configured correctly if you've adjusted both the artifact limits and nginx upload limits. Only other thing I can think of is to make sure your runner is also v15+ -- the `invalid argument` error message is maybe something to investigate.

Comment: My runner version is 15.0.0. I also looked into the runner's logs just now, but that does not seem to contain any useful information either. I'm thinkings about changing log levels to try and get some more useful information.

Comment: I have not found anything helpful in the logs. But I did come across more weird behaviours that lead me to classify this all as a Gitlab bug. One time, the upload just worked (even though the runner's log level was the one and only change I made), other times the upload produces HTTP 500 responses (even when changing nothing at all). I will probably leave it at that for the time being and instead change the pipeline to upload the result directly to the web server rather than storing it in an artifact for Gitlab. Not exactly what I wanted, but I have already wasted too many hours on this.